# recursive formula for an integral where $I_n$ is equal to $f(n)\cdot I_{n-1}$

Tags: calculus

I am unsure how to find a recursive formula for

$$\int_0^1 x^n.\sqrt {(1-x)}  dx = I_n$$

where $I_n = f(n) \cdot I_{n-1}$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts:
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \underbrace{x^n}_{u}\cdot \underbrace{\sqrt {1-x}  dx}_{dv}=\underbrace{-\frac{2}{3}x^n\cdot (1-x)^{3/2}\big{|}_0^1}_{=0}+\frac{2n}{3}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{3/2}x^{n-1}dx=$$
$$\frac{2n}{3}\int_0^1 (1-x)\cdot(1-x)^{1/2}x^{n-1}dx=$$
$$\frac{2n}{3}\int_0^1 (1-x)^{1/2}x^{n-1}dx-\frac{2n}{3}\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^{1/2}dx=\frac{2n}{3}I_{n-1}-\frac{2n}{3}I_n \Rightarrow $$
$$I_n=\frac{\frac23n I_{n-1}}{1+\frac23 n}.$$
Note:
$$I_0=\int_0^1 (1-x)^{1/2}dx=-\frac23 (1-x)^{3/2} \big{|}_0^1= \frac23,$$
$$I_1=\frac{\frac23 I_0}{1+\frac23}=\frac{4}{15}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember special function beta $$B(a,b)=\int _0^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1}\,dx$$
If we write
$$I_n=\int_0^1 x^n (1-x)^{\frac12}\, dx$$
we see that $a=n+1;\;b=\dfrac{3}{2}$

So $I_n=B\left(n+1,\dfrac{3}{2}\right)$

Remember an interesting property of Beta function
$$B(a,b)=\frac{ \Gamma(a)  \, \Gamma(b) }{\Gamma  (a+b)}$$
Thus we have

$I_n=B\left(n+1,\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac52\right)}$

While $I_{n-1}=B\left(n,\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)}$

So $\dfrac{I_n}{I_{n-1}}=\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac52\right)}\cdot \dfrac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}=\dfrac{2 n}{2 n+3}$

Concluding the recurrence is

$I_n=\dfrac{2 n}{2 n+3}\,I_{n-1}$

Hope this is useful